# How to show search suggestions from Database into JList while typing on JTextField in Java?

Tags: java, swing, search, jtextfield, jlist

I want to search data from database by typing into **JTextfield** with search suggestion.

I want that,while typing into **JTextField** and it will show the matching items(like suggestions while we search anything on google) from database into **JList**.

But while typing anything It shows only one name.It doesn't show other suggestions or matching items form database.

My code is given below:

```
    serialtext = new JTextField();
    serialtext.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    serialtext.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    serialtext.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
    serialtext.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            try {
            String ser = serialtext.getText();
            list.setVisible(true);
            listscrol.setVisible(true);
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from catagory where Category = ?");
            pst.setString(1, ser);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            //listload();
            
            DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();
            
            /*while(rs.next()) {
                DLM.addElement(rs.getString("Category"));
            }
            list.setModel(DLM);
            */
            if(rs.next() == true) {
                /*for(int i = 0; i < catagorytable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    DLM.addElement(rs.getString("Category"));
                    list.setModel(DLM);
                }*/
                /*String Name = rs.getString(1);
                String Status = rs.getString(2);*/
                
                DLM.addElement(rs.getString("Category"));
                list.setModel(DLM);
                //catname.setText(Name);
                //statusbox.setSelectedItem(Status);
            }
            else {
                catname.setText("");
                statusbox.setSelectedItem("");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            
        }
        }
    });
    serialtext.setBounds(250, 529, 201, 27);
    Catagory.add(serialtext);
    serialtext.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: I'm no SQL expert but your SQL query is looking for an exact match. So you would only ever return a single value when you find a match. Not sure but I think you need to use the "like" keyword in your SQL Read an SQL book or tutorial to find the exact format. Also, don't keep invoking setModel(...) in your loop. All you need to do is invoke the `addElement(...)` method to add data to the model. Finally variable names should NOT be fully capitalized. "DLM" is incorrect.

Comment: @camickr if i remove list.setModel, it gives me no output or result in the JList.

Comment: The setModel(...) statement need to be done outside the loop so it is only set once. So you can add it before you start the loop or after you finish the loop. I generally do it after the loop.

Comment: Actually, that is another problem with your code. You don't have a "loop". You only check the ResultSet for a single value. You need to add a while loop.

Comment: @camickr It works. But I want that when I pressed a key (suppose i press 'J' from Keyboard) it start showing suggestion.

Comment: @camickr now i use while loop and it works. But I want that when I pressed a key (suppose i press 'J' from Keyboard) it start showing suggestion.

Comment: Use a DocumentListener (not a KeyListener). Whenever a DocumentEvent is generated you invoke your logic to search the database. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for a basic example.

Comment: @camickr I use DocumentListener also. but it gives me the same output same as when i use while loop.

Comment: I can't debug your code for you. I have no idea what "same output" means. If you implement the DocumentlIstener correctly and your SQL is correct, then you should get the results you expect.

Comment: @camickr I get the output and it shows me the correct result.But I want that while I type it shows the results like the google searching. I think You can understand exactly what I want. :)

Comment: Yes I understand what you want. No I don't understand your problem. You just stated you get the output that you want. If you get the output you want you add that logic to the DocumentListener. Then the code will be executed every time you add/remove a character from the text field. The DocumentListener replaces the KeyListener.

Comment: You can download the `TableFilterDemo` example from the tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) which demonstrates how to invoke processing from the DocumentFilter.

Comment: @camickr Ok brother. Now I download TableFilterDemo and try again :) for fixing my main problem . Thanks me for helping a lot :)